# If there is no handshake, then it is worthless to check for passwords?

Tags: wireless

```
# aircrack-ng output-01.cap
Opening output-01.cap
Read 31484 packets.

   #  BSSID              ESSID                     Encryption

   1  00:11:22:33:44:55  SSIDHERE                    WPA (0 handshake)

Choosing first network as target.

Opening output-01.cap
Please specify a dictionary (option -w).


Quitting aircrack-ng...
#
```

**Q:** So if there is "0 handshake" in the capture file, then it means it will be impossible to get the password for the WPA test network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes as there has been no exchange of password between client and AP. So it is pretty much impossible.